# Analogue getTranslationTable() in ngx-translate

Tags: angular, angular-translate, ngx-translate

I'm trying to get a dictionary in ngx-translate in angular-translate for this was a function getTranslationTable() is there an analogue in ngx-translate?

Answer (score 0):

> **`getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any>`**: Gets an object of translations for a given language with the current loader

**Check the available [methods](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) here.**

Hope this is helpful!